# excel or c# or SQL solution to get count of periods

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, excel

i have a dataset that looks like this

```
id, value1,value2,value3,value4,value5...value200 (i am showing only 5 but solution needs to accomodate 200 values)
a, 10,4,2,0,0
b, 23,0,0,2,0
c, 0,2,4,0,0
d, 0,0,0,1,0
```

i would like to return the COUNT of how many values for each row, have ONLY zeros on the tails.

for the above data it would be:

```
3
4
2
1
```

the solution can either be c# or excel (formula, not vba)

thank you so much for your help./guidance and please let me know if i am not being clear

Comment: When you retrieve the data in C#, what data type is it in?  i.e., is it a `DataTable`/`IEnumerable<type>` with columns `id`, `value1`, etc., or a collection of CSV rows `IEnumerable<string>`, or what?

Comment: @mellamokb they are in a datatable

Comment: @mellamokb please view the answer i just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution i thought of:

1. concatonate the row of values
2. convert to a number (this will get rid of beginning zeros)
3. take mid() of the cell, ending at the starting position of first 0 (this will get rid of trailing 0's)
4. get length of final string (this will yield exactly the result needed)

Comment: That makes sense, when I had realised what you actually wanted I was thinking of something along similar lines. It does depend on how easy it is to concatenate your data a bit. Is your data in a spreadsheet already?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the file in as CSV data and parse it manually, you could do something like this to find the first non-zero entry at the beginning and end:

```
// prepare sample data (as CSV)
var csv =
@"id, value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
a, 10,4,2,0,0
b, 23,0,0,2,0
c, 0,2,4,0,0
d, 0,0,0,1,0";

// get column data
var lines = csv.Split('\n');
var rows = lines.Skip(1).Select (
    line => line.Split(',').Skip(1).Select (l => Convert.ToInt32(l)));
var result = new List<int>();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    // for each row, remove 0's at beginning and end
    var data = row.SkipWhile (r => r == 0).Reverse()
        .SkipWhile (r => r == 0).Reverse();
    // and retrieve the count
    result.Add(data.Count());
}
// result = [3, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: this is wonderful, can you please view the answer i just posted

Answer (score -1):

Excel array formula. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm formula entry:

```
=MAX((B2:F2>0)*COLUMN(B2:F2))-MATCH(1,--(B2:F2>0),0)-0
```

Note this assumes the data of interest begins at column B. The final `-0` needs to be changed if the data begins in a different column.

Comment: Neither of these return correct results: =COUNTIF($B3:$D3;">0") | =IF(RIGHT(D3,1)="0",1,0). They only return the count of [non]zero values, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: thanks so much for your help but this does not work, it returns error for just the first evaluation which is B2:F2

Comment: I tested it and it does work and returns the results you expected. Did you enter it as an array formula? You will get #VALUE error if you did not.

Comment: Just replace "F2" with "Z2" and all should be well. If this works for you would you kindly mark it as useful?

Comment: please test it before suggesting as an answer

Comment: @andy holaday My function does not return the count of zero values. That formula returns 1 if the cell's value ends in a zero, as required.

Comment: @sheepez can you please rephrase yourcomment, i do not understand

Comment: @Артём Царионов Could you explain what doesn't work? Error? Wrong answer? I replaced `F2` with `Z2` to give this formula: `=MAX((B2:Z2>0)*COLUMN(B2:Z2))-MATCH(1,--(B2:Z2>0),0)-0` , array-entered in cell AA2 and it works perfectly.

Comment: @sheepez inspection of the OP's sample data and results shows the "tail" needs to be considered at the _beginning_ of the data as well as the end.

Comment: @andy holaday Indeed it does, I had the wrong end of the stick, which is why I deleted my answer.

Comment: please view the asnwer i juyst posted

Comment: @sheepez please view the answer i just posted